# Getting the current logged in user in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, windows-authentication

I have a web application which authenticates users with AD according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx) article.
The impersonation if off because the code is running some files that need service_user permissions.
However, is some part of my code i need the Username of the currently authenticated user for security purposes (check if he is part of a certain AD group) or just to send him e-mails.

I have tried:

1. HttpContext.User Property.
2. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent Method.

They seem to return the application pool user, and not the logged in user.

Is there a way that i can get the username which is logged in for a current session?

Best,
Shimon.

Comment: Depend what kind of identtiy do You use. Try User.Identity.Name

Comment: Hi miechooy, i already tried it, it returns the user which the application pool is running under.

Comment: Fixed by using: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class for Application Session.

```
public class AppSession
{
public static string UserName
    {
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] != null)
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In Your Login.aspx page

```
 protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUserName.Text.Trim();
        string password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();

        if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            Profile userInfo = dc.Profile.Where(s => s.UserName == userName).SingleOrDefault();
           AppSession.UserName = userInfo.UserName;
        }
   }
```

Now you can get access UserName of currently logged in user.